# Find elements in an array not contained in another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array `arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]`
There is another array of objects `arr2 = [{'id':2, 'name':'A'},{'id':4, 'name':'B'}]`

I am looking for find elements in `arr1` which are not in `arr2`. The expected output is `[1,3,5]`

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
const arr = arr1.filter(i => arr2.includes(i.id));
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Try: `const arr = arr2.filter(i => arr1.includes(i.id))`. Since, `includes` is an array method and i doesn't have `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr2` is an array of objects, so `arr2.includes(i.id)` doesn't work because `i` (an item from `arr1`) is a *number*, which doesn't have an `id` property, *and* because `arr2` is an array of objects.

Turn `arr2`'s `id`s into a Set first, then check whether the set contains the item being iterated over:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const arr2 = [{'id':2, 'name':'A'},{'id':4, 'name':'B'}];

const ids = new Set(arr2.map(({ id }) => id));

const filtered = arr1.filter(num => !ids.has(num));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 2):

**A solution with O(arr2.length) + O(arr1.length) complexity in Vanilla JS**

```
var arr1= [1,2,3,4,5]; 
var arr2 = [{'id':2, 'name':'A'},{'id':4, 'name':'B'}];

var tmp = arr2.reduce(function (acc, obj) { 
    acc[obj['id']] = true; 
    return acc; 
}, {});

var result = arr1.filter(function(nr) { 
    return !tmp.hasOwnProperty(nr); 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
const arr2 = [{'id':2, 'name':'A'},{'id':4, 'name':'B'}]
const arr = arr1.filter(i => !arr2.some(j => j.id == i));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the filter method like below to check the condition required

```
    var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    var arr2 = [{ 'id': 2, 'name': 'A' }, { 'id': 4, 'name': 'B' }]
    var ids = [];
    arr2.forEach(element => {
        ids.push(element['id'])
    });

    var result = arr1.filter(s => ids.indexOf(s) < 0)
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr1= [1,2,3,4,5]; 
let arr2 = [{'id':2, 'name':'A'},{'id':4, 'name':'B'}]


let arr2Ids=arr2.map(item=>item.id); 
let result=arr1.filter(n => !arr2Ids.includes(n));
```

Comment: add relavant text to explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use find on `arr2` instead of includes since `arr2` is composed of object

```js
const arr = arr1.filter(i => !arr2.find(e => e.id===i));
```

Comment: Wouldn't [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) be more appropriate?